# Pycharm throws: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' error even though Numpy is installed

Tags: python, pycharm

When try to import numpy in pycharm it throws: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' error even though numpy is installed on the machine.

If I try to run the console it works perfectly.

Comment: How did you install numpy? The python env you use for pycharm must be the same env where you installed numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pycharm creates its own virtual environment. But you have installed numpy in your system environment.
**just open pychram console and run pip install numpy**

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

**Easy way: Use GUI**

File --> Settings --> Project Interpreter

Next you search for Numpy package and install desired package

**Hard Way: Use command prompt**

Go to terminal and upgrade pip first by typing the following

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Next, install the package

```
 pip install numpy
```

**Verification**

After installation is complete, please verify by typing following commands in console

```
  import numpy as np
  print (np.__version__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open pycharm console

Open File, Select ---> Settings, Select ---> Project Interpreter

Open the terminal and run the below command to upgrade pip.

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

run the commands to install the package

```
 pip install numpy
```